# customize state of disabled radio radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button, state

Hello i am trying to implement a seat reservation system using radio buttons.
Basically the state of all the radio buttons (seat) will be red, but when checked it goes to green which i have successfully found out a way to do,

but now i want to implement a disabled state for radio buttons (seat) that have supposedly been registered by a user using a disabled state for that radio button.

so that it can not be selected anymore
this is what i have presently

```
<style type="text/css">
[type=radio]{
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px
}

[type=radio]:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: -15px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: red
}

[type=radio]:checked:before{
    background: green;
}

[type=radio]:checked:before:disabled{
    background: black;
}


</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type= "radio" name= "radio" />
<input type= "radio" name= "radio" />
<input name= "radio" type= "radio" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

from the snippet above i was trying yo implement a disabled state which would be a third state as black for disabled radio buttons (registered seats) bt it dosent seem to work any advice pls, thanks

Comment: Chain it this way: `checked:disabled:before`

Comment: its stiil red i expect it to go black, did you try it before posting it

Comment: [I didn't, but I know it works](https://jsfiddle.net/atewbf5x/)

Comment: radio button background color works ???

Comment: [Actually, a new challenger has arrived. Mixed results apparently](https://jsfiddle.net/atewbf5x/1/)

Comment: it didnt work, please check and see ohGodwhy

Comment: [Here's another possible solution](https://jsfiddle.net/atewbf5x/2/)

Comment: from the fiddle you gave me there is nothing black there

Comment: ohhh the second is better, please wait let me test

Comment: @user3215045 : why dont make one jsfiddle ,,,, its your part.. you should do it

Comment: hello ohGodwhy, the disabled, but the present state is supposed to be unchecked, then when you check the color changes to green. do u understand what am saying, now theres a state missing

Comment: thanks though, i adjusted it now, it works the way i want, please post an answer, so i can like it for your score ohGodwhy